# How to query the blockchain data ?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, solc

I am developing an KYC dapp where I am keeping customer information like name, dob, age etc. Each customer is having an account address ( i.e Ethereum account). Basically this is a private blockchain. I can able to search into blockchin by customer's ethreum account. I can able to get the customer's details by querying with "ethereum account address". My question here is , Can we search/get details by customer's name ? Or do we need to search by only his ethereum account ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi there. Is there any advantage to doing this in a blockchain instead of a (perhaps distributed) database?